# Is there a name for this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, perl

Apologies for the non-descriptive question; if you can think of a better one, I'm all ears.

I'm writing some Perl to implement an algorithm and the code I have smells fishy. Since I don't have a CS background, I don't have a lot of knowledge of standard algorithms in my back pocket, but this seems like something that it might be.

Let me describe what I'm doing by way of metaphor:

- You have a conveyor belt of oranges. The oranges pass you one by one. You also have an unlimited supply of flat-packed boxes.
- For each orange, check it. If it is rotten, dispose of it
- If it is good, put it in a box. If you don't have a box, grab a new one and construct it.
- If the box has 10 oranges in it, close it up and put it on a pallet. *Do not* construct a new one.
- Repeat until you have no more oranges
- If you have a constructed box with some oranges in it, close it up and put it on a pallet

So, we have an algorithm for processing items in a list, if they meet some criteria, they should be added to a structure which, when it meets some other criteria, should be 'closed out'. Also, once the list has been processed, if there's an 'open' structure, it should be 'closed out' as well.

Naively, I assume that the algorithm consists of a loop acting over the list, with a conditional to see if the list element belongs in the structure and a conditional to see if the structure needs to be 'closed'.
Outside the loop, there would be one more conditional to close any outstanding structures.

So, here are my questions:

1. Is this a description of a well-known algorithm? If so, does it have a name?
2. Is there an effective way to coalesce the 'closing out the box' activity into a single place, as opposed to once inside the loop and once outside of the loop?

I tagged this as 'Perl' because Perlish approaches are of interest, but I'd be interested to hear of any other languages that have neat solutions to this.

Comment: +1 for very very clear explanation of what you are asking for.

Comment: Henceforth this shall be known as "the Dancrumb Procedure". I'll get working on the Wiki page.

Comment: 1. No. 2. Make a function called `close_box()` and call it in 2 places.  That's what functions *are for*, there's nothing morally suspect about doing this :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker: true, a function would simplify it, but it does leave the opportunity for the second function call to get deleted or shunted into the wrong scope by a careless maintainer.
I'll grant you that you can't avoid all evils, but I am left wondering if there's a way to do it with the function call in only one place.

Comment: As it happens Perl lets you attach a `continue` block to the end of the loop -- you could call `if ($n == 10 || $no_more_oranges) { close_box() }` just once in there.  But `continue` is a seldom-used construct, and I would guess it's more likely to confuse a future maintainer than just calling the function twice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a nice fit with a functional approach - you're iterating over a stream of Oranges, testing, grouping and operating on them. In Scala, it would be something like:

```
 val oranges:Stream[Oranges] = ... // generate a stream of Oranges

 oranges.filter(_.isNotRotten).grouped(10).foreach{ o => {(new Box).fillBox(o)}}
```

(`grouped` does the right thing with the partial box at the end)

There's probably Perl equivalents.

Comment: I haven't really started to learn Scala yet...but does the `new Box.fillBox(o)` really only create a new box for the *first* item in the group, or would it create a new box for every element?

Comment: Oh, I suppose `o` is actually a collection of oranges?  If so that makes sense then.

Comment: +1 for the functional approach. That's what immediately comes to functional minds when reading the question!

Answer (score 5):

> Is there an effective way to coalesce the 'closing out the box' activity into a single place, 
>   as opposed to once inside the loop and once outside of the loop?

Yes. Simply add "... or there are no more oranges" to the "does the structure need to be closed" function. The easiest way of doing this is a do/while construct (technically speaking it's NOT a loop in Perl, though it looks like one):

```
my $current_container;
my $more_objects;
do {
    my $object = get_next_object();  # Easiest implementation returns undef if no more 
    $more_objects = more_objects($object) # Easiest to implement as "defined $object"
    if (!$more_objects || can_not_pack_more($current_container) { 
        close_container($current_container);
        $current_container = open_container() if $more_objects;
    }
    pack($object, $current_container) if $more_objects;
} while ($more_objects);
```

IMHO, this doesn't really win you anything if the `close_container()` is encapsulated into a method - there's no major technical or code quality cost to calling it both inside and outside the loop. Actually, I'm strongly of the opinion that a convoluted workaround like I presented above is WORSE code quality wise than a straightforward:

```
my $current_container;
while (my $more_objects = more_objects(my $object = get_next_object())) {
    if (can_not_pack_more($current_container)) { # false on undef
        close_container($current_container);
    }
    $current_container = open_container_if_closed($current_container); # if defined
    pack($object, $current_container);
}
close_container($current_container);
```

Comment: To clarify a comment for non-perlheads in the audience: of course `do`/`while` "is a loop" in a practical sense, but the `do`-block isn't a "loop block" for the purpose of loop-control verbs like `next` and `last`. It's just a `do BLOCK` that happens to be governed by statement-modifier `while`.

Comment: +1, the 2nd way is clearer.  `close_container()` should be a separate method *so that* it can be called in both places (if for no other reason).

Answer (score 3):

It seems like a bit over-complicated for the problem you are describing, but it sounds theoretically close to Petri Nets. check [Petri Nets on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_net)

A perl implementation can be found [here](http://search.cpan.org/~drrho/Graph-PetriNet-0.03/lib/Graph/PetriNet.pm)

I hope this will help you,

Jerome Wagner

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a name for this algorithm. For a straight-forward implementation you'll need two tests: one to detect a full box while in the processing loop and one after the loop to detect a partially full box. The "closing the box" logic can be made into a subroutine to avoid duplicating it. A functional approach could provide a way around that:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(part natatime);

my ($good, $bad) = part { $_->is_rotten() } @oranges;

$_->dispose() foreach @$bad;

my $it = natatime 10, @$good;
while (my @batch = $it->()) {
    my $box = Box->new();
    $box->add(@batch);
    $box->close();
    $box->stack();
}
```

Comment: Your implementation has different complexity from described one. Calling `part` will make (materialize) two arrays so it will take O(`N`) memory. Original algorithm is O(`1`).

Answer (score 0):

When looking at algorithms, the mainstream CS ones tend to handle *very* complex situations, or employ *very* complex approaches (look up [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete) for example). Moreover, the algorithms tend to focus on optimization. How can this system be more efficient? How can I use less steps in this production schedule? What is the most amount of foos that I can fit in my bar? etc.

An example of a complex approach in my opinion is quick sort because the recursion is pretty genius. I know it is standard, but I really like it. If you like algorithms, then check out the [Simplex Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) - it has been very influential.

An example of a complex situation would be if you had oranges that go in, get sorted into 5 orange piles, then went to 5 different places to be peeled, then all came back with another path of oranges to total 10 orange piles, then each orange was individually sliced, and boxed in groups of *exactly* 2 pounds.

Back to your example. Your example is a simplified version of a [flow network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network). Instead of having so many side paths and options, there is only one path with a capacity of one orange at a time. Of the flow network algorithms, the [Ford-Fulkerson algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) is probably the most influential.

So, you can probably fit one of these algorithms into the example posed, but it would be through a simplification process. Basically there is not enough complexity here to need any optimization. And there is no risk of running at an inefficient time complexity so there is no need to be running the "perfect approach".

The approach you detailed is going to be fine here, and the accepted answer above does a good job suggesting an actual functional solution to the defined problem. I just wanted to add my 2 cents with regards to algorithms.